# Sort nsmutablearray into decending order based on index

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have stored 3 values into an NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[myArray addObject:DateTimeString];
```

now need to show this array into uitableview but i want to show the list based on descending order of the index value of array

I dont know how to sort the array into acending order based on index - i want to rearrange. i mean i want to show recently added object first

Please let me know how to do that

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:([myArray count]-row-1)];
```

Doesn't this work ?

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
NSArray* reversed = [[myArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```